# HTML to PDF first page Blank

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-to-pdf

I'm converting `HTML to PDF` and its working fine but the issue is when I generate PDF first page of PDF is blank. All records are set from second page of that PDF.

I'm Using Codeigniter framework.And using below package

```
 @package   Html2pdf
 * @author    Laurent MINGUET <webmaster@html2pdf.fr>
 * @copyright 2017 Laurent MINGUET
```

Below is the code which doing all that.

```
try {
            $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
            $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
            $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
            $html2pdf->output($pdfname.'.pdf','D');
        } catch (Html2PdfException $e) {
            $html2pdf->clean();

            $formatter = new ExceptionFormatter($e);
            echo $formatter->getHtmlMessage();
        }
```

Below is `html` content

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Invoice</title>
        <style type="text/css">

        body {background-color: rgb(204,204,204); margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        .header {margin-bottom: 40px;}
        /*.header div {width: 700px;}*/
        .text-right {text-align: right;}
        .table-value td { border-bottom: 1px solid #e7ecf1;
        border-right: 1px solid #e7ecf1;
        border-left: 1px solid #e7ecf1;}
        .table-value th{ border-top: 1px solid #e7ecf1;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #c8c8c8;
        border-right: 1px solid #e7ecf1;
        border-left: 1px solid #e7ecf1;}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- <page size="A4"> -->
        <div class="header">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%; font-size: 11pt;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="1" style="width: 360px;">
                        <img src="http://test.com/assets/image-2019-05-13-16-32-28-565.png" style="width: 60%;">
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="1" valign="middle" style=" text-align: right; width: 350px;">
                        <p style="margin: 0;">Test</p>
                        <p style="margin: 0;">Test</p>
                        <p style="margin: 0;">Test</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>   
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-box" style="padding-bottom: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; margin-bottom: 50px;">
                <p style="color: #d71383;font-size: 36px;margin-bottom: 10px;">Test</p>
                <p></p>
                <div style="line-height: 20px;">
                    <div style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;" id="client-name">Test: <span>##COMPANYNAME##</span></div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;" id="client-contact">Test: <span>##USERNAME##</span></div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;" id="client-email">E-mail: <span>##EMAIL##</span></div>
                    <p></p>
                    <div style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;" id="uren-periode">Test: <span>##FROMDATETODATE## </span></div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;" id="datum">Test: <span>##TODAYDATE##</span></div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;" id="total-aantal-uren">Total: <span>##HOURMIN##</span></div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;" id="hourly-rate">Test: <span>##HOURLYRATE##</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-value-box">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table-value" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"  style="max-width: 800px;margin: 0 auto; font-size: 11pt;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 60px;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;line-height: 5px; height: 25px;"><span>Ticket #</span></th>
                                <th style="width: 100px;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;line-height: 5px; height: 25px;"><span>Datum</span></th>
                                <th style="width: 288px;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;line-height: 5px; height: 25px;"><span>Onderwerp</span></th>
                                <th style="width: 158px;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;line-height: 5px; height: 25px;"><span>Tijd</span></th>
                                <th style="width: 100px;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;line-height: 5px; height: 25px;"><span>Status</span></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            ##DATA##
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--   </page> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you creating the $html2pdf object twice? Could you check if that's the issue?

Comment: @arjithn i have updated question and added html content also. please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Without calling the constructor twice, Try the following :

```
 try {

            $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr', true, 'UTF-8', [2, 2, 2, 5]);
            $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
            $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
            $html2pdf->output($pdfname.'.pdf','D');
        } catch (Html2PdfException $e) {
            $html2pdf->clean();

            $formatter = new ExceptionFormatter($e);
            echo $formatter->getHtmlMessage();
        }
```

Also the number of pages and placement of page breaks depends highly on the structure of your html content. An empty `<page>` tag or a misplaced `<div>` could also create troubles while using **html2pdf**.

Incase the above solution doesn't workout , please post sample html document content, esp.the  first few lines from the source of the browser, will try to help

Comment: For me when I tried with the above HTML content I didn't get any extra blank page. Did you check your css?